# Removing slash in url (not trailing slash)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a folder named people on my server, and index.php in that folder
My url is like **mydomain.com/people/?name=value1&age=value2**

But I really want it to look like **mydomain.com/people?name=value1&age=value2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since "people" is a folder and your script is in that folder, the only way for this to work is if you turn off `DirectoryIndex`, which automatically redirects the browser to include a trailing slash for any request that's for a folder.

Note, this **is a trailing slash**, the URI ends with `/people/`. The `?` and everything after it is the query string.

Turning off `DirectoryIndex` can be very dangerous, as it is used to prevent information disclosure. Without a trailing slash on your folders, requesting a folder will result in displaying the contents of that folder *even if you have a directory index*. In other words, `index.php` is ignored and instead, you get a listing of all your folder's contents. So to prevent that from happening, you have to internally add the slash back.

So something like this in the htaccess file of your document root:

```
DirectoryIndex Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+people/\?
RewriteRule ^ /people [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) you can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R,QSA]
```

`QSA` here is not required since it stands for Query String Append and it's on by default.